# Eclipse POJO generator plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, pojo

Does anyone know of a good Eclipse POJO generator? The generate getter\setters and constructor from fields functions are all really nice, but it would be useful to have that tied into a new class\POJO dialog.

Comment: Plain Old Java Object generator? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an Eclipse plug-in, but here's one way to generate Java beans. Define the schema using [Relax NG Compact syntax](http://www.relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html), convert it to XML Schema (xsd file), and generate Java code using JAXB ([xjc](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/xjc.html)).